# Как поместить в один слушатель несколько операций?

Tags: java, swing

[image: Как должно выглядеть]
Здравствуйте. Мне нужно в один слушатель ActionListener поместить работу сразу со всеми кнопками. Для каждой кнопки свой слушатель создать не подходит. Вот код:

```java
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class P4_2 implements ActionListener 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new T2());}
  public void run() {  
    JPanel windowContent= new JPanel();
    windowContent.setLayout(null);
    JButton obr = new JButton("ШАБЛОН");
    JButton style = new JButton("СТИЛЬ");
    JButton p = new JButton("АБЗАЦ");
    JButton style1 = new JButton("ШРИФТ");
    JButton zyr = new JButton("ЖИРНЫЙ");
    JButton curs = new JButton("КУРСИВ");
    JButton cav = new JButton("<>");
    JButton cav1 = new JButton("<></>");
    JButton ink = new JButton("ССЫЛКА");
    JButton enter = new JButton("ПЕРЕНОС");
    JButton list = new JButton("СПИСОК N");
    JButton list1 = new JButton("СПИСОК *");
    JButton line = new JButton("ЛИНИЯ");     
    JTextArea derzy = new JTextArea(20,20);
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(20,20);
    JScrollPane re = new JScrollPane(text);
    text.setLineWrap(true); 
    derzy.setLineWrap(true);
    windowContent.setLayout(null); 
    windowContent.add(obr);
    windowContent.add(style);
    windowContent.add(p);
    windowContent.add(style1);
    windowContent.add(derzy);
    windowContent.add(zyr);
    windowContent.add(curs);
    windowContent.add(text);
    windowContent.add(re);
    windowContent.add(cav);
    windowContent.add(cav1);
    windowContent.add(ink);
    windowContent.add(enter);
    windowContent.add(list);
    windowContent.add(list1);
    windowContent.add(line);
    obr.setBounds(5,5,100,40);
    style.setBounds(110,5,100,40);
    p.setBounds(215,5,100,40);
    style1.setBounds(320,5,100,40);
    zyr.setBounds(425,5,100,40);
    curs.setBounds(530,5,100,40);
    cav.setBounds(5,50,100,40);
    cav1.setBounds(110,50,100,40);
    ink.setBounds(215,50,100,40);
    enter.setBounds(320,50,100,40);
    list.setBounds(425,50,100,40);
    list1.setBounds(530,50,100,40);
    line.setBounds(5,95,100,40);
    derzy.setBounds(5,350,690,155);
    text.setBounds(700,5,500,500);
    re.setBounds(640,5,50,300);
    text.setLineWrap(true);
    derzy.setLineWrap(true);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Помощник по HTML");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
    frame.setSize(1225,550);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    obr.addActionListener(this);
    style.addActionListener(this);
    p.addActionListener(this);
    style1.addActionListener(this);
    zyr.addActionListener(this);
    curs.addActionListener(this);
    cav.addActionListener(this);
    cav1.addActionListener(this);
    ink.addActionListener(this);
    enter.addActionListener(this);
    list.addActionListener(this);
    list1.addActionListener(this);
    line.addActionListener(this);   
  }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("ШАБЛОН")){ 
derzy.setText("<html>"+ "\n" + "<title>"+ "\n" + "</title>"+ "\n" + "<body>"+ "\n" + "</body>"+ "\n" + "</html>");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("СТИЛЬ")){
derzy.setText("<style type=\"text/css\">"+ "\n" + "p{font-size:16px; font-family:Comic Sans MS}"+ "\n" + "h1{font-size:20px; font-family:Comic Sans MS}"+ "\n" + "h2{font-size:18px; font-family:Comic Sans MS}"+ "\n" + "</style>");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("АБЗАЦ")){
derzy.setText("<p>  </p>");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("ШРИФТ")){
derzy.setText("<p style=\"font-size:16px; font-family:Comic Sans MS\">  </p>");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("ЖИРНЫЙ")){
derzy.setText("<b>  </b>");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("КУРСИВ")){
derzy.setText("<i>  </i>");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("<>")){
derzy.setText("< >");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("<></>")){
derzy.setText("< >  </ >");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("ССЫЛКА")){
derzy.setText("<a  title=\" \" href=\"https://www.google.com.ua/\">     </a>");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("ПЕРЕНОС")){
derzy.setText("<br/>");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("СПИСОК N")){
derzy.setText("<ol>"+ "\n" + "<li>  </li>"+ "\n" + "<li>    </li>"+ "\n" + "</ol>");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("СПИСОК *")){
derzy.setText("<ul>"+ "\n" + "<li>  </li>"+ "\n" + "<li>    </li>"+ "\n" + "</ul>");}
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("ЛИНИЯ")){
derzy.setText("<hr/>");}
    }   
}
```

Вот пример работающей программы, где на каждую кнопку свой слушатель:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class P3 implements ActionListener 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    JPanel windowContent= new JPanel();
    windowContent.setLayout(null); 
    JTextArea derzy = new JTextArea(20,20);
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(20,20);
    JScrollPane re = new JScrollPane(text);
    text.setLineWrap(true);
    derzy.setLineWrap(true);
    JButton obr = new JButton("ШАБЛОН");
    JButton style = new JButton("СТИЛЬ");
    JButton p = new JButton("АБЗАЦ");
    JButton style1 = new JButton("ШРИФТ");
    JButton zyr = new JButton("ЖИРНЫЙ");
    JButton curs = new JButton("КУРСИВ");
    JButton cav = new JButton("<>");
    JButton cav1 = new JButton("<></>");
    JButton ink = new JButton("ССЫЛКА");
    JButton enter = new JButton("ПЕРЕНОС");
    JButton list = new JButton("СПИСОК N");
    JButton list1 = new JButton("СПИСОК *");
    JButton line = new JButton("ЛИНИЯ");
// Добавляем компоненты на панель
    windowContent.add(obr);
    windowContent.add(style);
    windowContent.add(p);
    windowContent.add(style1);
    windowContent.add(derzy);
    windowContent.add(zyr);
    windowContent.add(curs);
    windowContent.add(text);
    windowContent.add(cav);
    windowContent.add(cav1);
    windowContent.add(ink);
    windowContent.add(enter);
    windowContent.add(list);
    windowContent.add(list1);
    windowContent.add(line);
    windowContent.add(re);
    re.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    re.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    text.setCaretPosition(0);

    obr.setBounds(5,5,100,40);
    style.setBounds(110,5,100,40);
    p.setBounds(215,5,100,40);
    style1.setBounds(320,5,100,40);
    zyr.setBounds(425,5,100,40);
    curs.setBounds(530,5,100,40);
    cav.setBounds(5,50,100,40);
    cav1.setBounds(110,50,100,40);
    ink.setBounds(215,50,100,40);
    enter.setBounds(320,50,100,40);
    list.setBounds(425,50,100,40);
    list1.setBounds(530,50,100,40);
    line.setBounds(5,95,100,40);


    derzy.setBounds(5,350,690,155);
    text.setBounds(700,5,480,483);
    re.setBounds(700,5,497,500);
// Создаём фрейм и задаём для него панель 
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Помощник по HTML"); 
    frame.setContentPane(windowContent);
// задаём и размер и делаем фрейм видимым
    frame.setSize(1240,550);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    obr.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
      derzy.setText("<html>"+ "\n" + "<title>"+ "\n" + "</title>"+ "\n" + "<body>"+ "\n" + "</body>"+ "\n" + "</html>");
    }
});
    style.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
      derzy.setText("<style type=\"text/css\">"+ "\n" + "p{font-size:16px; font-family:Comic Sans MS}"+ "\n" + "h1{font-size:20px; font-family:Comic Sans MS}"+ "\n" + "h2{font-size:18px; font-family:Comic Sans MS}"+ "\n" + "</style>");
    }
});
    p.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
      derzy.setText("<p>    </p>");
    }
}); 
    style1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
      derzy.setText("<p style=\"font-size:16px; font-family:Comic Sans MS\"> </p>");
    }
}); 
    zyr.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          derzy.setText("<b>    </b>");
        }
    }); 
    curs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          derzy.setText("<i>    </i>");
        }
    });
    cav.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          derzy.setText("< >");
        }
    });
    cav1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          derzy.setText("< >    </ >");
        }
    });
    ink.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          derzy.setText("<a  title=\"   \" href=\"https://www.google.com.ua/\">     </a>");
        }
    }); 
    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          derzy.setText("<br/>");
        }
    });
    enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          derzy.setText("<br/>");
        }
    });
    list1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          derzy.setText("<ul>"+ "\n" + "<li>    </li>"+ "\n" + "<li>    </li>"+ "\n" + "</ul>");
        }
    });
    list.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          derzy.setText("<ol>"+ "\n" + "<li>    </li>"+ "\n" + "<li>    </li>"+ "\n" + "</ol>");
        }
    });
    line.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
          derzy.setText("<hr/>");
        }
    });





    }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{        }

}
```

Comment: Не понятно, что Вы хотите? Что означает ` поместить работу сразу со всеми кнопками`? Что он должен делать?

Comment: То, что он должен делать, уже написано в коде. Я просто не понимаю, как создать слушатель, который будет получать результат e.getActionCommand().

Comment: почему не хотите создавать слушателя для каждой кнопки? Чем конкретно это не устраивает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `e.getSource.equals(переменная_JButton)`

```
if(e.getSource().equals(obr)){ 
derzy.setText("<html>"+ "\n" + "<title>"+ "\n" + "</title>"+ "\n" + "<body>"+ "\n" + "</body>"+ "\n" + "</html>");}
```